# Linq Age GroupBy Aggregate Count

Tags: c#, linq, count, aggregate

I have problems getting the correct result of this linq.

```
 var transactions = from trans in tblMemberInfo.AsEnumerable()
                    orderby trans.Field<Int32>("AGE") ascending
                    group trans by trans.Field<Int32>("AGE") into groupTrans

                    select new
                    {                                      
                         ZeroToSix = groupTrans.Count(age => age.Field<Int32>("AGE") >= 0 && age.Field<Int32>("AGE") <= 6) 
                    };
```

I have a data table which contains data below. now, I want to sum all the age count where 
age is between 0 to 5.

```
AGE     Count
0       6
1       6
2       7
3       5
4       5
5       20
6       5
7       5
8       5
9       5
10      5
```

I would like to see the result like this.

```
Age

ZeroToFive = 49
AboveSix = 25
```

Comment: Do you have `Count` property in objects of `tblMemberInfo`, or do you mean that you have it in `transactions` var?

Comment: yep i have count property.

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
// mock data
var data = new List<dynamic> {
    new { Age = 0, Count = 6 },
    new { Age = 1, Count = 6 },
    new { Age = 2, Count = 7 },
    new { Age = 3, Count = 5 },
    new { Age = 4, Count = 5 },
    new { Age = 5, Count = 20 },
    new { Age = 6, Count = 5 },
    new { Age = 7, Count = 5 },
    new { Age = 8, Count = 5 },
    new { Age = 9, Count = 5 },
    new { Age = 10, Count = 5 },
};

var age = new { 
                ZeroToFive = data.Where(x => x.Age < 6).Sum(x => x.Count),
                AboveSix = data.Where(x => x.Age >= 6).Sum(x => x.Count)
              };
```